# pip cannot fetch URL because of an error with the SSL certificate

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pip

When I try to install pip through the cmd, whit this command:

```
python get-pip.py
```

It throws me this error:

> "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem
>   confirming the ssl certifica te: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Cau sed by
>   SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
>   available.")) - skipping".

And I don't know to fix it, maybe some of you knows how to fix it.

Comment: what os and version of python are you using ... try to upgrade python

Comment: os : windows 7 and python 3.7

Comment: can you try pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

Comment: i tried what you said @MD5 and it did not work, but thank you anyway i appreciate it

Comment: check by  deleteing these two files C:/Windows/System32: libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll or try installing openssl from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some other ways to install pip

**Pip install**

For pip install in the safe side, we can run some command to prepare our ubuntu
In Ubuntu open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install build-essential python-dev python3-dev python-setuptools
```

Once the update is complete the pip install is very easy for the latest Ubuntu. Only you can run the following code in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

if need pip install specific python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Pip installed successfully.

**Pip install with curl**

An alternative way to install pip: 
It is another easy way to install pip by using Curl and python.

```
sudo apt-get update
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python get-pip.py
```

Now verify the pip installation:
Write the pip on the terminal. You can see some codes.

If you want to check the version of

`pip -V`

**For windows**

You can uninstall python and try to install it again
When you get this kind of windows
[image]

Must check Add Python3.6 to PATH
It will automatically install the pip without any problem. I test it.

If also face issues comment below

Comment: I am working on windows, i don't know much about this, but i think maybe this won't work on windows, or if you tell me otherwise, i could try it

Comment: you are using windows which version? I update my above instruction for windows

Comment: i am using windows 7 and python 3.7